# Ordenar columnas de treeview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un hilo en el que preguntaba como generar un treeview a partir de un dataframe de pandas en python. El hilo es este:

[Como usar ProgressBar de Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194353/como-usar-progressbar-de-tkinter)

Mi problema ahora es que no se como implementar una función que ordene cada columna al hacer clic en su cabecera. Yo antes generaba el treeview de otra manera y usaba algo así para hacer lo que estoy comentando pero ahora no se adaptarlo.

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
l.sort(reverse=reverse)

# rearrange items in sorted positions
for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
    tv.move(k, '', index)

# reverse sort next time
tv.heading(col, command=lambda: \
           treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))




tv.heading('#1', text="text", command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, '#1', False))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `DataFrameTreeView` expone el `TreeView` interno mediante el atributo de instancia `tree_view`, el cual puedes usar para acceder al widget tanto desde la misma clase mediante `self.tree_view` como desde la instancia (`self.treeview.tree_view` en este caso desde `Application`). Esto es lo que tienes que usar en lugar de `tv`, lo más apropiado sería hacer que la función sea un método de instancia de la clase:

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import pandas as pd



class DataFrameTreeView(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tree_view = None
        self.hscrollbar = None
        self.vscrollbar = None

    def load_table(self, df, columns=None, columns_headers=None, chunk_size=100):

        """
        Args:
            path: cadena -> ruta al fichero .xlsx
            columns: list -> columnas a mostrar en la tabla, si es None se,muestran todas
            columns_headers: list -> Nombres para las cabeceras de las columnas,
                                     si es None se usan las cabeceras del DataFrame

            chunk_size: int -> Número de filas creadas por iteración
        """ 

        if columns is not None:
            dif = set(columns) - set(df.columns)
            if dif:
                raise ValueError(f"Columns: {tuple(dif)} are not in DataFrame") 
        else:
            columns = df.columns

        if columns_headers is not None:
            if  len(columns_headers) != len(df.columns):
                raise ValueError("headers length not mismath columns number")
        else:
            columns_headers = columns
        tk_col_names =[f"#{name}" for name in columns_headers]

        # Treeview y barras
        if self.tree_view is not None:
            self.tree_view.destroy()
            self.hscrollbar.destroy()
            self.vscrollbar.destroy()

        self.tree_view = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=tk_col_names)
        self.vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command = self.tree_view.yview)
        self.vscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill=tk.Y)
        self.hscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command = self.tree_view.xview)
        self.hscrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill=tk.X)
        self.tree_view.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscrollbar.set)
        self.tree_view.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hscrollbar.set)

        # Configuar columnas y cabeceras
        for name, header in zip(tk_col_names, columns_headers):
            self.tree_view.column(name, anchor=tk.W)
            sort_f = functools.partial(self.treeview_sort_column, name, False)
            self.tree_view.heading(name, text=header, anchor=tk.W,
                                   command=sort_f)
        # Cargamos los items
        rows = df.shape[0]
        chunks = rows / chunk_size
        progress = 0
        step = 100 / chunks

        progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal",
                                        length=100, mode="determinate")
        progress_bar["value"] = progress 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Cargando filas")
        label.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.45, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        progress_bar.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.80,  anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for ind in df.index:
            values = [str(v) for v in df.loc[ind, columns].values]
            self.tree_view.insert("", tk.END, text=ind+1, values=values)
            if ind % chunk_size == 0:
                self.update_idletasks()
                progress += step
                progress_bar["value"] = progress 

        progress_bar["value"] = progress
        self.update_idletasks()

        progress_bar.destroy()
        label.destroy()
        self.tree_view.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


    def treeview_sort_column(self, col, reverse):
        l = [(self.tree_view.set(k, col), k) for k in self.tree_view.get_children('')]
        l.sort(reverse=reverse)

        for index, (_, k) in enumerate(l):
            self.tree_view.move(k, '', index)

        self.tree_view.heading(col,
            command=lambda: self.treeview_sort_column(col, not reverse)
            )
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que la lista que se obtiene a partir del `Treeview` y la cual ordenamos **es siempre una lista de cadenas**. Esto implica que el ordenamiento que se realiza es **lexicográfico**, lo cual no es posiblemente lo que queramos si la columna contiene escalares por ejemplo, ya que `[1, 5, 19, 255]` se ordena como `[1, 19, 255, 5]`. La solución más simple es realizar el casting oportuno dependiendo del tipo de la columna  al generar la lista:

```
l = [(int(self.tree_view.set(k, col)), k)
         for k in self.tree_view.get_children('')]
```

Esto puede llegar a ser complicado de generalizar y ineficiente para columnas con muchos elementos. Dado que tus datos proceden de un DataFrame, una opción mucho más simple y eficiente es almacenar una copia de los datos mostrados en un DataFrame, si nos aseguramos de que cada columna tiene el tipo adecuado antes de enviarlo a la instancia de `DataFrameTreeView` es trivial usar ese DataFrame para ordenar la columna sin el problema mencionado anteriormente  y de forma más eficiente:

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import pandas as pd



class DataFrameTreeView(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tree_view = None
        self.hscrollbar = None
        self.vscrollbar = None
        self._data = None

    def load_table(self, df, columns=None, columns_headers=None, chunk_size=100):

        """
        Args:
            path: cadena -> ruta al fichero .xlsx
            columns: list -> columnas a mostrar en la tabla, si es None se,muestran todas
            columns_headers: list -> Nombres para las cabeceras de las columnas,
                                     si es None se usan las cabeceras del DataFrame

            chunk_size: int -> Número de filas creadas por iteración
        """ 

        if columns is not None:
            dif = set(columns) - set(df.columns)
            if dif:
                raise ValueError(f"Columns: {tuple(dif)} are not in DataFrame") 
        else:
            columns = df.columns

        if columns_headers is not None:
            if  len(columns_headers) != len(df.columns):
                raise ValueError("headers length not mismath columns number")
        else:
            columns_headers = columns
        tk_col_names =[f"#{name}" for name in columns_headers]

        # Treeview y barras
        if self.tree_view is not None:
            self.tree_view.destroy()
            self.hscrollbar.destroy()
            self.vscrollbar.destroy()

        self.tree_view = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=tk_col_names)
        self.vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command = self.tree_view.yview)
        self.vscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill=tk.Y)
        self.hscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command = self.tree_view.xview)
        self.hscrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill=tk.X)
        self.tree_view.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscrollbar.set)
        self.tree_view.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hscrollbar.set)

        # Configuar columnas y cabeceras
        for name, header, col in zip(tk_col_names, columns_headers,  columns):
            print(name)
            self.tree_view.column(name, anchor=tk.W)
            sort_f = functools.partial(self.treeview_sort_column, name, False)
            self.tree_view.heading(name, text=header, anchor=tk.W, command=sort_f)

        # Cargamos los items
        rows = df.shape[0]
        chunks = rows / chunk_size
        progress = 0
        step = 100 / chunks

        progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal",
                                        length=100, mode="determinate")
        progress_bar["value"] = progress 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Cargando filas")
        label.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.45, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        progress_bar.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.80,  anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for ind in df.index:
            values = [str(v) for v in df.loc[ind, columns].values]
            self.tree_view.insert("", tk.END, text=ind+1, values=values)
            if ind % chunk_size == 0:
                self.update_idletasks()
                progress += step
                progress_bar["value"] = progress 

        progress_bar["value"] = progress
        self.update_idletasks()

        progress_bar.destroy()
        label.destroy()
        self.tree_view.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        self._data = df[columns].copy()
        # Creamos columna en dataframe local con los items
        self._data.columns = tk_col_names
        self._data["#iids"] = self.tree_view.get_children('')


    def treeview_sort_column(self, col, reverse):
        """
        Ordena el treeview al hacer click en la cabecera de cada columna
        de forma alterna en orden ascendente y descendente.

        """
        self._data.sort_values(by=col, inplace=True,  ascending=reverse)        
        for index, iid in enumerate(self._data["#iids"]):
            self.tree_view.move(iid, '', index+1)

        sort_f = functools.partial(self.treeview_sort_column, col, not reverse)
        self.tree_view.heading(col, command=sort_f)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El precio a pagar es el uso de más memoria obviamente al tener que mantener este DataFrame en memoria mientra el TreeView exista.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba. Una duda FJSevilla, es normal que para un dataframe de unos 25000 registros tarde en ordenar las columnas unos 5-6 segundos?

Comment: Ummmm el problema es ordenar el widget, ordenar el DataFrame en si no lleva casi nada de tiempo.  En mi caso para 25000 filas ordenar el DataFrame conlleva unos 5 milisegundos si se ordena en base a columnas de escalares (o similares) como Datetime, int, float o bool y unos 13 milisegundos para cadenas que siempre es más lento. El problema es que el for que ordena el Treeview una vez ordenados los datos lleva de 2.5 a 3 segundos en mi caso...

Comment: El for en sí apenas lleva 1-2 milisegundos, el problema es las 25000 llamadas al método `Treeview.move`... Lo verdaderamente lento parece estar por tanto del lado de tcl/tk no de Python por lo que no veo fácil optimizar esto...

Comment: Vale, en todo caso, muchas gracias.